# Cómo evitar cache en PHP y XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp

Estoy presentando un raro caso de cache que me tiene como loco, ya no sé por donde buscarle.
Después de una actualización de hardware, me vi en la necesidad de reinstalar varias aplicaciones, entre ellas XAMPP, aproveche e instalé la última versión (v.8.0.11).
A partir de ese momento si yo hacía cambios en el código en localhost, los cambios no se veían reflejados en el navegador, se cargaba siempre una versión anterior del código. Podía incluso eliminar un archivo, que al refrescar el navegador seguía mostrando la versión anterior del código sin cambios.
Limpié el caché del navegador, pensé que eso lo iba a solucionar pero no... seguía igual.
Abrí la página desde un nuevo navegador (que nunca había usado para abrir la página) y que me muestra el mismo contenido anterior sin cambios!!! Definitivamente el problema no estaba en el caché del navegador.

El código PHP tiene todos los headers para evitar el caché:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header ("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0'); // HTTP/1.1
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
```

Siguiendo indicaciones, me fui a XAMPP al archivo httpd.conf y comenté la siguiente línea:

```
LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
```

En php.ini, tengo:

```
opcache.enable=0
```

Al no ver cambios, reinstalé la versión de XAMPP que tenía antes de suceder el problema (7.4.10) y sucede exactamente lo mismo.

Ya no sé dónde buscarle, ya no sé qué hacer.

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Dale un título más descriptivo a tu pregunta: recuerda que otros usuarios puede que tengan el mismo problema, y no llegarían a esta pregunta si la misma se titula "Raro caso de PHP que no logro resolver". Lee [ask] y pulsa en [edit] para realizar las mejoras correspondientes.

Comment: Prueba a cambiar en tu php.ini la opción `opcache.enable=0`

Comment: Hola padeleiana, ya edité el título de la pregunta, gracias

Comment: Hola @kalia,   ya en el php.ini está con valor 0 el opcache.enable. Fue uno de los primeros cambios que me sugirieron, pero ni aún así funciona.

Comment: Estás utilizando algún framework??

Comment: Sí, estoy usando ExtJS, que es un framework JavaScript

Comment: Que tenes en .htaccess?

Comment: Hola, ya se solucionó... el problema estaba en el framework ExtJS que uso, el archivo app.js no se estaba actualizando y se seguía cargando sin los cambios, por eso dada la impresión de que se cargaba de un caché, copié una versión anterior de ese archivo y ya todo funciona perfecto. Gracias por el apoyo!